# Showing MongoDB records that do not match the schema or are empty/null

Tags: c#, mongodb, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor app based on [BlazorSQLandMongoDb](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/combine-sql-db-and-mongodb-in-same-blazor-app2/)

Using the example data here [MongoDb Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/introduction/)

My .razor:

```
   <MudTable Items="structuredDatas" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm">
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Qty</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Rating</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Edit</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Delete</MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="name">@context.Name</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="qty">@context.Qty</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="score">
                @foreach (var rating in context.Ratings)
                {
                    <div>@rating.Score</div>
                }
            </MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
    </MudTable>
```

This works as long as every record matches the schema (that is to say has every field of the document) and every field is not empty or null.

1. How do I get it to return all requested fields of a record and ignore unrequested fields even if the record does not match the schema exactly?
2. How do I get it to return a record even if a field is empty/null?

This will be critical should I need to revise or add to the schema later.

**Update**

I updated my code with the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` decorator. This works if I remove any field except Ratings which contains a list. (e.g. `"Ratings": [ { "score": 8 }, { "score": 9 } ]`)

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class StructuredData
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Qty { get; set; }
   public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

The page loads but no table if I take Rating out. Still haven't figured this part out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved last issue with:

```
<MudTd DataLabel="Score">
    @if (context.Ratings != null)
    {
        @foreach (var rating in context.Ratings)
        {
            <div>@rating.Score</div>
        }
    }
</MudTd>
```

Which may also solve first issue...